# Adding choice to field associated to Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-type

I have the following script :

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://TEST123")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$ct=$web.ContentTypes["MyCT"]  
$field = $ct.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("AddTESTColumn")                            
$ct.FieldLinks[$field.id].DisplayName ="AddTESTColumn"     
$ct.Update();
```

I have used the above to update the display name of a column that is associated to CT.

But now I want to update a choice field column so will be adding a new choice "away" to the current choices tried to use the choices.add but keep getting error message

I used the following :

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://TEST123"

$web = $site.RootWeb
$field = 
$web.Fields["AddTESTColumn"];
$field.choices.add("away")
$field.update();
```

and get the following message:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

the issue is with `$field = $web.Fields["AddTESTColumn"];` as its not recognising the field name even though it exist. I have used both internal and display name, same issue.

Comment: please add the code you tried for adding the choice.

Comment: what's the error message that you are getting ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please remember that the field names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes made sure of that, just tested it with another choice field in the content type works ok for that something with that column its just not liking the name

Comment: Just to confirm, if you run the following, you can find your column, and the Title matches what you're using in the script?  $web.fields | select title,internalname | sort title |  ft

Comment: did that already to get the internal name but when i use that internal or display name it doesn't recognise it

Comment: Can you check if the field is present in Site Columns?

Comment: Yes its present i had a script to update all the list where that column was used they worked fine update but the column in the content type that's what l need to update and isn't

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Site Column then your code is fine.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://TEST123"    
$web = $site.RootWeb
$field = $web.Fields["SiteColumnInternalName"];
$field.choices.add("away") 
$field.update();
```

If it is a list column and not a site column, then try the code below.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://TEST123"    
$web = $site.RootWeb
$List = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$field = $list.Fields.GetField("ColumnInternalName");
$field.Choices.Add("away") 
$field.update();
```